# Selecting a value based on a datetime reference

Tags: r, date, datetime, conditional-statements, filtering

Hello Guys hope everyone is doing well!

I'm currently working on two data sets one contains the records of repairs of machines in a textile industry and the other data set contains the record of the preventive maintenance that a machine received.

| MACHINE | REPAIR_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| X | 6/03/2021 |
| Y | 24/02/2021 |
| F | 28/02/2021 |
| O | 27/02/2021 |
| O | 18/02/2021 |
| O | 12/02/2021 |
| U | 7/02/2021 |
| U | 8/01/2021 |
| U | 2/01/2021 |
| H | 1/02/2021 |
| H | 4/02/2021 |
| H | 12/03/2021 |
| H | 22/03/2021 |

the second datebase looks like this

| MACHINE | MAINTENANCE_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| X | 4/03/2021 |
| F | 29/02/2021 |
| M | 26/02/2021 |
| L | 25/02/2021 |
| U | 16/02/2021 |
| H | 10/02/2021 |
| H | 5/02/2021 |
| H | 6/01/2021 |

What I am trying to achieve is creating a dataframe where I can see for **each** machine repair's date when was the very last maintenance date **PRIOR** to that specific repair (also hopefully using tidyverse since Im learning but if you guys think that this cant be solved using tidyverse thats not a problem I also wanna learn as much from you). for instance

```
MACHINE REPAIR_DATE LAST_MAINTENANCE_DATE_PRIOR_TO_REPAIR
F       28/02/2021           N.A
```

This is because we have a record of maintenance for machine F that has performed AFTER the repair date, and we are looking for the latest maintenance date before the repair date.

**What am I doing?**

I thought about arranging both datasets in chronological order to later on joining them then grouping by MACHINE and REPAIR_DATE but I am finding myself struggling with conditioning that the latest maintenance date should be prior to the date of repair, and I have to construct a data frame with all machines repair dates and their respective latest maintenance date. I have also a bit of confusion when it comes to joining the table since there will be some N.As if I do a full join by a "dummy variable" or even if a just join the two datasets lets say by doing something like all<-c(dataset1,dataset2) , thank you guys for helping me out and teaching me, You guys are the best and coolest people on earth!

CODE:

```
ds1<-tribble(
  ~MACHINE,  ~REPAIR_DATE,
  "X",  "6/03/2021",
  "Y",  "24/02/2021",
  "F",  "28/02/2021",
  "O",  "27/02/2021",
  "O",  "18/02/2021",
  "O",  "12/02/2021",
  "U",  "7/02/2021",
  "U",  "8/01/2021",
  "U",  "2/01/2021",
  "H",  "1/02/2021",
  "H",  "4/02/2021",
  "H",  "12/03/2021",
  "H",  "22/03/2021")

ds2<-tribble(
  ~MACHINE,  ~MAINTENANCE_DATE,
  "X",  "4/03/2021",
  "F",  "29/02/2021",
  "M",  "26/02/2021",
  "L",  "25/02/2021",
  "U",  "16/02/2021",
  "H",  "10/02/2021",
  "H",  "5/02/2021",
  "H",  "6/01/2021")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

ds1 %>%
  mutate(REPAIR_DATE = dmy(REPAIR_DATE)) %>%
  left_join(ds2 %>% 
              mutate(MAINTENANCE_DATE = dmy(MAINTENANCE_DATE)), 
            by = 'MACHINE') %>% 
  group_by(MACHINE, REPAIR_DATE) %>%
  summarise(LAST_MAINTENANCE_DATE = {
      val <- REPAIR_DATE - MAINTENANCE_DATE
      if(any(val > 0, na.rm = TRUE)) 
        max(MAINTENANCE_DATE[val > 0], na.rm = TRUE)
      else NA
    }
    ) %>%
  ungroup

#  MACHINE REPAIR_DATE LAST_MAINTENANCE_DATE
#   <chr>   <date>      <date>               
# 1 F       2021-02-28  NA                   
# 2 H       2021-02-01  2021-01-06           
# 3 H       2021-02-04  2021-01-06           
# 4 H       2021-03-12  2021-02-10           
# 5 H       2021-03-22  2021-02-10           
# 6 O       2021-02-12  NA                   
# 7 O       2021-02-18  NA                   
# 8 O       2021-02-27  NA                   
# 9 U       2021-01-02  NA                   
#10 U       2021-01-08  NA                   
#11 U       2021-02-07  NA                   
#12 X       2021-03-06  2021-03-04           
#13 Y       2021-02-24  NA
```

Join the two datasets and for each unique `REPAIR_DATE` of `MACHINE` find the last `MAINTENANCE_DATE`.

Comment: Helo @Ronak thank you SO much for your code! This helped me out a lot. I'm just an R student... I would be so thankful if you could help me out understanding what did you do in the summary portion of the code, what does the val variable represents and  why is it important to remove NAs? Thank you so much again

Comment: `val` has difference between the dates `REPAIR_DATE` and `MAINTENANCE_DATE`. With `val > 0` we keep only the maintenance date that occurred prior to repair date and select the `max` date from it. It is important to remove `NA`'s because `max` with `NA` returns `NA`. See the difference in output between `max(1, 2, NA)` and `max(1, 2, NA, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: OMG, I forgot something I am so sorry @RonakShah what if in the first dataset for each  REPAIR_DATE I also have a unique repair_code lets say OPW_999, how can I add this unique repair code to the final data set, I have tried by grouping by (REPAIR_CODE, MACHINE, AND REPAIR:DATE) by in my dataset some dats may be the same which end up assigning the same REPAIR_CODE to the wrong machine... thank you so much for helping me out I promise this will be my last inquiry thanks a lot

Comment: Well, I would have said the same to `group_by` , `REPAIR_CODE` to keep it in final dataset but if it doesn't work as expected in `summarise` you might want to add `REPAIR_CODE = first(REPAIR_CODE)` to get the first one.